# Which fixes are enabled by ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES hint in sql server 2016?

Tags: sql-server

I have found that the 'ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES' query hint greatly improves cardinality estimation accuracy in my azure sql server 2016 database with compatibility level 130 and 'Legacy Cardinality Estimation = Off'.

My question: How can I see which 'fixes' this query hint is toggling? (I understand this hint should enable any fix released 'post sql server 2016 RTM' but I can't find a listing of those fixes anywhere.)

I would like to understand the root cause of this issue and this is my best lead so far.

**Context**

The query below returns 15,581 results.

```
select 
    RegistrationId from Registrations 
where 
    EventId = 1234
    and IsDeleted = 0
OPTION(
--USE HINT('ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES'), 
recompile)
```

**Without** the 'ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES' hint the CE predicts 124 rows.

**With** the hint the CE predicts 16,750.

Quite a difference! (I understand the difference is immaterial in this simplified query, but I believe these poor estimations are causing the query optimizer to choose bad plans in larger, more complex queries).

Other findings/notes:

- Inverting the IsDeleted predicate (and IsDeleted != 1) returns a 'good' estimation (16,750)
- Query hint 'FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION' returns a 'good' estimation  (16,750)
- Removing IsDeleted predicate returns a 'good' estimation (17,108)
- Statistics are up to date.
- EventID and IsDeleted are part of a multi-column non-clustered index (IX_RegistrationEventID)
- EventID = 1234 is a RANGE_HI_KEY value for IX_RegistrationEventID stats and has EQ_ROWS = 17100.22

Answer (score 2):

> **QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES**
>
> Enables or disables query optimization hotfixes regardless of the
> compatibility level of the database. The default is OFF, which
> disables query optimization hotfixes that were released after the
> highest available compatibility level was introduced for a specific
> version (post-RTM). **Setting this to ON is equivalent to enabling Trace
> Flag 4199.**

And according to document: [SQL Server query optimizer hotfix trace flag 4199 servicing model](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/974006/sql-server-query-optimizer-hotfix-trace-flag-4199-servicing-model):

> Trace flag 4199 was used to collect hotfixes that were intended to
> become on-by-default in a future release, whereas other trace flags
> were used for situations in which a fix was not intended to become
> on-by-default in current form. Starting with SQL Server 2016 RTM, the
> database COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL setting will be used enable trace flag
> 4199-related hotfixes on-by-default. This article describes the
> mechanics and policy of how plan-affecting hotfixes will be delivered
> for SQL Server 2016 and later versions.
>
> The following table lists trace flags that were used for query
> processor hotfixes before the introduction of trace flag 4199:

```
Microsoft Knowledge Base article    Trace flag
318530                                 4101
940128                                 4102
919905                                 4103
920346                                 4104
920347                                 4105
922438                                 4106
923849                                 4107
926024                                 4108
926773                                 4109
933724                                 4110
934065                                 4111
946793                                 4115
950880                                 4116
948445                                 4117
942659                                 4119
953948                                 4120
942444                                 4121
946020                                 4122
948248                                 4124
949854                                 4125
959013                                 4126
953569                                 4127
955694                                 
957872                                 4128
958547                                 4129
956686                                 4131
958006                                 4133
960770                                 4135*
```

> My question: How can I see which 'fixes' this query hint is toggling?

One of those from the list above

> (I understand this hint should enable any fix released 'post sql
> server 2016 RTM'

Yes, that is correct, since QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES is Trace flag 4199 which runs on a database level

A decent compilation of the discovered trace flags: https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SQL%20Server%20Trace%20Flag.md

It shows that 4136-4139 were introduced during SQL Server 2016 SP1, perhaps those four you are looking for